# Redirecting to a page after Firebase login - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase to create a web app using their simple login/signup template. I was just wondering how I can redirect to a different page after a successful login or otherwise run a javascript function code which I have on the same page only for logged in users.
Thanks

Reference:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js

The template I am using is under the auth/email.html

Thanks!