# AngularJS and Firebase Authentication invoke Routing after the second click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, routes, firebase-authentication

I'm working on Firebase Authentication with Angular, I bumped into a problem that `$location.path` function only invoked after I clicked on the second time, the first time, I run this `loginVerify`, Firebase authenticated the visitor into a user but it didn't route to my contact page, the second time I click, Firebase authenticated the visitor into a user again and route the user to the landing page. Can anyone help me to find out why? Thank you very much!

Source code: https://github.com/ptchiangchloe/Meet-Up-Event-Planner

And here is my live version: https://meet-up-event-planner-d45a4.firebaseapp.com/#!/

```
vm.loginVerify = function() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(vm.email, vm.password))
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("Success!", response); // the first I run this fn, firebase authenticate the visiter is a user but it didn't route to my contact page
      $location.path('/contacts');// the second time I click, firebase authenticate the visiter is a user again and route the user to my contact page
    }).catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorCode);
      console.log(errorMessage);
      $location.path('/');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figure out the problem after I read [How to redirect after a user signs in with Firebase authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033520/how-to-redirect-after-a-user-signs-in-with-firebase-authentication/38035812#38035812)
The problem is I don't need to redirect, instead, I need to change the state of my app since it's a single-page app. I didn't fully understand how the state works.

And I could just simply set the window location using JavaScript in your success callback instead of using Angularfire. Someone told me don't mix jQuery with Angular if possible, or you will run into errors. So I guess that maybe it's the problem before.

Here are my new code.

```
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(vm.email, vm.password)
    .then((firebaseUser) => {
        return firebaseUser
    })
    .then((firebaseUser) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
        if (firebaseUser) {
          window.location = '/#!/contacts'
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorCode);
      console.log(errorMessage);
    });
```