# In Firebase, after authenticating login, how do I redirect and also prevent non-logged in people from accessing sub pages?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set up a simple authentication mechanism on Firebase.  I have a user account that I can authenticate with.

1. After successful login, how do I get the user to redirect to the dashboard page?   Right now I am just doing `window.location = dashboard.html` but that doesn't redirect.  In addition, another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033520/how-to-redirect-after-a-user-signs-in-with-firebase-authentication) said that I might not need to redirect but change the application state instead.  How do I do that?  I have two HTML files, `index.html` with the login form and `dashboard.html` so how do I get the dashboard info to show without redirecting?
2. How do I prevent non-users from accessing the Dashboard directly by just adding `dashboard.html` to the end of the URL?

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <h1>Sign-In</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <input id="txt_email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input id="txt_password" type="password" placeholder="Password">

        <button id="btnLogin">Log In</button>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<body>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {

    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      //config info here
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    // Get elements
    var txt_email = document.getElementById("txt_email");
    var txt_password = document.getElementById("txt_password");
    var btnLogin = document.getElementById("btnLogin");

    // Add click listener to Log in button
    btnLogin.addEventListener("click", e => {
        //Get username and password
        var email = txt_email.value;
        var password = txt_password.value;
        const auth = firebase.auth();

        //Sign in
        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
    });


    //Add a realtime authentication listener
    //fires every time an authentication state changes
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
        if(firebaseUser)
        {
            console.log(firebaseUser);
            window.location = "dashboard.html";
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("not logged in");
        }
    });

}());
```

Edit: Do I need the `form` tag in my HTML?  Almost all the tutorials out there don't have it but they are just showing how authentication works.  If I do need it, what should the `action` attribute be?

Edit2: I wrapped email/password inputs and button in an HTML `form` tag but it only successfully logs in if I have `action="#"`.  If I did `action="/"` or `action=""`, it doesn't log in at all.  I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are at least four things going on here: the difference between clients and servers, how HTML forms work, events and synchronicity, and how to secure a Firebase app.

## Clients and Servers

HTML pages and scripts in them run on the client-side in a browser, and are public. Once pages and scripts are served to the client, users cannot be prevented from accessing them. Firebase runs on the server-side and can protect data behind authentication, on the server-side. You enable that protection by setting up authentication and data access rules within Firebase. This does not effect users' access to client-side pages or scripts.

## HTML Forms

Buttons and inputs can be included in HTML with or without a form element. Form elements are only needed for submitting input to a server, for server-side processing, directly from the page. You are using client-side scripts to gather input from the page and submit them. So, you do not need a form element for your purposes.

The action attribute refers to the address where a form should be submitted. "/" refers to the root path on the server, and an empty string refers back to the current path. "#" would refer to a named anchor within the current page (but with no name).

## Events and Promises

A form with any action besides a named anchor would prevent your scripts from working. This is because submitting a form without canceling the event, directs the browser away from the current page, destroying the client-side execution context. In your case, even though you called auth before returning from the event handler, the script would not work without canceling the event--because promises are asynchronous, so the promise would be created but the execution context would be destroyed before the promise completed.

## Securing Firebase Apps

It might be useful to think in terms of providing a public client-side, and secure server-side for your app. You can provide a *shell* of a user interface through *static* HTML and JavaScript that you don't mind being public. You could choose to include the login interface and dashboard on the same page, or on separate pages, with that design choice being up to you. It is probably the actual dynamic data and contents within the shell of the user interface, that you want to secure. Again, you can setup rules to secure that data, within Firebase. Then, you can use client-side scripts (or a framework) within you page to send data back and forth between the dashboard and Firebase.

You can use client-side scripts (or a framework) to show and hide certain parts of certain pages for when they are relevant to the data you have, (but not to prevent access to such content, as it is already client-side). You might want to do this, for example, to show the login interface when the user is not logged in, or to hide the login interface and show the dashboard when the user is logged in and the dashboard will be populated with relevant data from Firebase.